# How do I make the options in Power BI Tile View Slicers all on the same row?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, slicers

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z1sP.png)]
As seen in the attached image, when I create a slicer in Power BI and do a tile view it creates it in two rows of options. I would like these to all be on one row but I cannot seem to find an option for that.

I have checked all the Slicer settings.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already discovered this by now or someone else may have told you, but if you reduce the height of the slicer it should rearrange them to all be on one row horizontally.